# React state not correct when function called via addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a React component that uses state to manage a `changed` variable if a form input is updated.

Assuming I've made some updates to the form, the issue I'm having is if I dispatch a click event to the `onCancel` function using `addEventListener` the value of `changed` is not correct but if I call `onCancel` from the JSX the value is correct.

Any ideas?

```
const Edit = (props) => {
  let [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);

  // Fired when a form value is updated
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setChanged("true");
  };

  // Close modal
  const onCancel = () => {
    console.log(changed); // This will be false when triggered from addEventListener
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let form = document.querySelector(".oda-edit-form");
    // Close Window on click outside
    form.addEventListener("click", function () {
      onCancel();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
      <button onClick={onCancel}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re render your component as soon your state changes to run the onCancel() funtion.

```
    let form = document.querySelector(".oda-edit-form");
    // Close Window on click outside
    form.addEventListener("click", function () {
      onCancel();
    });
  }, [changed]);  // < ----- add dependancy
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Does this method not add the event listener multiple times?

Comment: You can add a assign this event listener to a constant, say eventID. And then return the useEffect function with removeEventListener(eventID) so that it removes it everytime it is unmounted

Comment: I decided to refactor as I wasn't using the correct approach here. I added an onClick directly to the container and created a new method for handling the click. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the `addEventListener` and added an `onClick` directly to the JSX with a custom method.

```
const Edit = (props) => {
  let [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);

  // Fired when a form value is updated
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setChanged("true");
  };

  // Close modal
  const onCancel = () => {
    console.log(changed); // This will be false when triggered from addEventListener
  };

  const onClickOutside = (e) => {
    let element = e.target.querySelector('.wide-card');
    let isClickInside = element.contains(event.target);
    // // Close Modal
    if (!isClickInside) {
        onCancel();
    }
   };

  return (
    <div onClick-{(e)=>onClickOutside(e)}>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
      <button onClick={onCancel}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```